# passport.js Linkedin OAuth returns "cannot fetch user profile"

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js, linkedin-api

I use the passport.js strategy `passport-linkedin-oauth2` to make users of my system log in via linkedin.
They do get to the "sign in" page, where they fill in their email address and password, and "grant access" but when they do, they return to my callback page, where an error is shown: "Cannot fetch user profile".

Navigating to `/` or `/phone` works

this is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
const plinkedin = require('passport-linkedin-oauth2').Strategy;
const works = path.join(__dirname, 'works.html');
const worksnot = path.join(__dirname, 'worksnot.html');

passport.use(
    new plinkedin({
        clientID: clientID,
        clientSecret: clientSecret,
        callbackURL: "http://localhost:4000/auth/linkedin/callback",
        profileFields: [
            "id",
            "positions"
        ],
        scope: ['r_emailaddress', 'r_liteprofile', 'w_member_social'],
        passReqToCallback: true
    }, function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        console.log('a');
        process.nextTick(function() {
            console.log('something is working'); //is not logged
        });
    }));

const server = express()
    .get('/auth/linkedin', passport.authenticate('linkedin', {
        state: 'gekkeSTATE'
    }), function(req, res) {
        console.log('authenticate1')
    }) //is not logged
    .get('/auth/linkedin/callback', passport.authenticate('linkedin', {
        successRedirect: '/works',
        failureRedirect: '/worksnot'
    }, console.log('authenticate2'))) //is logged first
    .get('/works', (req, res) => res.sendFile(works))
    .get('/worksnot', (req, res) => res.sendFile(worksnot))
    .listen(4000);
console.log(4000) //is logged 2nd
```

I expected the user being directed to either `/works` or `/worksnot`, but instead, the user is directed to `http://localhost:4000/auth/linkedin/callback?code=AQSIbPg5hakpi_HnHl1azUGnTASZkLoqUwAP9cL4zqPwKnGNT792KCC9Q52HLbGOAqKSwE20moJy9poijiMLtIpPCEQkN-ld53aigyHb5dUXr3ef3PGjLVsk6nxAqzcOYKt3HN95uJXahiCAXLSWIRO_BecK-EwwY4bOsWm6emLipn4muDnwtGPTfDI1Sg&state=gekkeSTATE`, where they see "InternalOAuthError: failed to fetch user profile".

The console output:

```
authenticate2
4000

InternalOAuthError: failed to fetch user profile
    at _oauth2.get (C:\Users\Maarten\iCloudDrive\node_modules\passport-linkedin-oauth2\lib\oauth2.js:62:21)
    at passBackControl (C:\Users\Maarten\iCloudDrive\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:132:9)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Maarten\iCloudDrive\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:157:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1094:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Comment: Are you sure you've added `http://localhost:4000/auth/linkedin/callback` to the list of allowed redirect URLs in your app's settings? Also, double-check your ClientID and ClientSecret. They're on the same page where redirect URLs are. I've just finished testing your code on a temporary LinkedIn account. It works - the last console output is "something is working". Btw. you need to add `return done(null, profile);` to process.nextTick's callback. Otherwise, the browser won't be redirected further and will simply hang.

Comment: @TomaszKasperczyk yes, I have added it to my list of redirect urls. thats probably also why i get directed to /auth/linkedin/callback, with some parameters at the end. I double-checked my ID and Secret, and added return done(null, profile);, but nothing changes. 
It is very odd that you managed to get 'something is working' while i havent ever seen that in my console. very weird.
I can share with you my entire folder of files if you want.

Comment: The latest version of the code in GitHub may resolve this issue; see https://github.com/auth0/passport-linkedin-oauth2/issues/102#issuecomment-1781370868